# how can i read inbox in android mobile?

Tags: android

i want read Sms inbox in android mobile via android application.Any one know this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the content resolver,

```
  Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
    Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(
            mSmsinboxQueryUri,
            new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date",
                    "body", "type" }, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(cursor1);
    String[] columns = new String[] { "address", "person", "date", "body",
            "type" };
    if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
        String count = Integer.toString(cursor1.getCount());
        Log.e("Count",count);
        while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {
            out.write("<message>");
            String address = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                    .getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
            String name = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                    .getColumnIndex(columns[1]));
            String date = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                    .getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
            String msg = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                    .getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
            String type = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                    .getColumnIndex(columns[4]));
}
 }
```

This will read both inbox and sent items.If you want to read the inbox or sent items alone then you specify it in content resolver.

```
   Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
   Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
```

For reading your SMS you must add uses-permission in androidmanifest.xml,

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Comment: this code works well..can u tell how can i block the outgoing sms

Comment: @adithi do you know how to get the count per contact in the inbox?

Answer (score 2):

using the content

```
    ArrayList<String> smsList = new ArrayList<String>();
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query( Uri.parse( "content://sms/inbox" ), null, null,null,null);
int indexBody = cursor.getColumnIndex( SmsReceiver.BODY );
int indexAddr = cursor.getColumnIndex( SmsReceiver.ADDRESS );
if ( indexBody < 0 || !cursor.moveToFirst() ) return;
    smsList.clear();
do
{
    String str = "Sender: " + cursor.getString( indexAddr ) + "\n" + cursor.getString( indexBody );
    smsList.add( str );
}
while( cursor.moveToNext() );
```

User-Permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Comment: Please, add the import string for SmsReceiver class

Answer (score 1):

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),null,null,null, null);
startManagingCursor(c);

int smsEntriesCount = c.getCount();

    String[] body = new String[smsEntriesCount];
    String[] number = new String[smsEntriesCount];

    if (c.moveToFirst()) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < smsEntriesCount; i++) 
        {
            body[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
            number[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    c.close();
```

you also needs permission. include following line in menifest.xml

```
<uses-permission name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```