# how to go the Default SMS Screen/Phonebook from our application

Tags: android

**My question is that from our application can we go to the Default SMS Screen/Phonebook**

**For example :-** I create tabbar with three tab (Inbox,Phonebook,Group).To press Inbox I want to go the default SMS screen which is provided by Android or To press Phonebook I want to go the phonebook screen which is provided by Android.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PhoneBook you can startActivity with intent ACTION_VIEW;

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
 startActivity(intent);
```

For inbox see this today's answer [how can i read inbox in android mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547352/how-can-i-read-inbox-in-android-mobile/5547454#5547454)

Comment: thanks you solve my one problem,but I can't read the Inbox, i want to go default screen of message as you suggested for contacts

Comment: This works for me:
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
   intent.setComponent(
       new ComponentName("com.android.mms","com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList"));     But you should remember that it is not documented and could be changed by Google.