# Unable to read the sms

Tags: android

this is my code

```
public class SMSRead extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      TextView view = new TextView(this);
      Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
      Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);
      String sms = "";
      while (cur.moveToNext()) {
          sms += "From :" + cur.getString(2) + " : " + cur.getString(11)+"\n";         
      }
      view.setText(sms);
      setContentView(view);
  }
}
```

I tried with this code.But did not get the SMS in my app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i read inbox in android mobile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547352/how-can-i-read-inbox-in-android-mobile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the `SMS_READ_PERMISSION` in android **manifest file** . i think the code is ok .

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Comment: oh...so silly i am...just forget to use it... thanks